# How to check a dictionary where values are lists for an element of that list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

If I have a dictionary where each value is a list, how can I check if there is a specific element in my list? For example:

```
myDict = { 0 : ['a','b','c'],
           1 : ['d','e','f']}
```

How can I check if `'a'` exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Check all values

We can use [**`itertools.chain`**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and use it in a rather self-explaining *one liner*:

```
from itertools import chain

if 'a' in chain.from_iterable(myDict.values()):
    # do something
    pass
```

Here we will chain the `.values()` of a list together in an iterable, and thus check membership of `'a'`.

Note that this runs in *linear* time with the total number of values in the lists. In case you have to perform the membership check a single time, we can not do much about it, but in case we have to check it multiple times, it is better to cache the values in a set (given the values are hashable).

## Check a specific key

In case you want to check a specific key, we can just lookup the corresponding value and check membership:

```
if 'a' in myDict[0]:
    # do something
    pass
```

In case it is not certain if the key is present in `myDict`, and we want to return `False` in that case, we can use `.get(..)` and use `()` (the empty tuple) as a fallback value:

```
# will not error, but False in case key does not exists
if 'a' in myDict.get(0, ()):
    # do something
    pass
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
any('a' in lst for lst in myDict.values())
```

This will stop the iteration and evaluate to `True` on the first find. `any` is the built-in short-cut for the following pattern:

```
for x in y:
    if condition:
        return True
return False
# return any(condition for x in y)
```

Comment: Thanks, do you also know of a way to search just one key, for example, if I want to search for 'a' by only looking through key 0?

Comment: @carmo: That's just `'a' in myDict[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

It always strikes me as strange when someone wants to scan the values of a dictionary. It's highly unefficient if done many times.

Instead, I'd build another dictionary, or a `set` for quick check:

```
myDict = { 0 : ['a','b','c'],
           1 : ['d','e','f']}

rset = {x for v in myDict.values() for x in v}

print(rset)
```

gives:

```
{'b', 'e', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'f'}
```

now:

```
'a' in rset
```

is super fast and concise. Build as many sets & dictionaries as you need on your original data set to get a fast lookup.